# Hardware encoding with nanopi2 fire under linux

Tags: c++, linux, encoding, hardware, nanopi

I am trying to encode raw frames with nanoPi 2 fire board computer.
I have founded api for it:
https://github.com/friendlyarm/nexell_linux_platform

Accroding to nx_video_api.h I need to open device, init it, alocate memory for input and output frame, and then push encoding with "NX_VidEncJpegRunFrame".

However that is the problem, can anyone help me with alocating memory for this structure "NX_VID_ENC_IN"?
How to put raw frame there? What pixel format it should be?
How to read data back from "NX_VID_ENC_OUT"?

I cannot find any sample or tutorial for hw encoding on that chip, so any example would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the Github project in the question theser is a sample that show how to use NX_VidEncJpegRunFrame (in [NXJpegHWEnc.cpp](https://github.com/friendlyarm/nexell_linux_platform/blob/master/nanocams/NXJpegHWEnc.cpp)).

You can allocate the structure NX_VID_ENC_OUT on the stack, the output buffer will be allocated by NX_VidEncJpegRunFrame :

```
NX_VID_ENC_OUT encOut;
NX_VidEncJpegRunFrame(hEnc, &memInfo, &encOut);
```

Next you can access to buffer `encOut.outBuf` of `encOut.bufSize`.